# jenkins pipeline, unstash from a sub job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a separate `build` pipeline that uses `jenkinsfile` to build the code.
I trigger it from a `deploy` pipeline and want to get build results.

The reason for this is that devs can define build steps but deploy is out of there control.

Here's a sample code in `jenkins job builder`:

```
- job:
    name: Build and Deploy
    project-type: pipeline
    dsl: |
      node {
        stage('Build') {
          # that job does stash inside a jenkinsfile
          build job: "Build"
          sh 'cp -rv "../Build/dist/" ./' # this is a workaround
          stash includes: 'dist/*.zip', name: 'archive'
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
          unstash 'archive'
          sh "..."
        }
      }
```

So how can I `unstash` code `stash`-ed in a sub-job?

P.S.: there's also a workaround with artefacts:

In a sub-job:

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.zip', fingerprint: true
```

main DSL:

```
    dsl: |
      node {
        def build_job_number = 0
        def JENKINS = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
        stage('Build') {
          def build_job = build job: "Build"
          build_job_number = build_job.getNumber()
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
          sh "wget -c --http-user=${USER} --http-password=${TOKEN} --auth-no-challenge ${JENKINS}/job/Build/${build_job_number}/artifact/name.zip"
          sh "..."
        }
      }
```

The issue here is that  API token is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with `archiveArtifacts` you can use [`copyArtifacts`](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to complement it.

As far as I know `stash`/`unstash` only work within the same job, so your other option would be to tick the `Preserve stashes from completed builds` in the pipeline's configuration so you can re-use them.